# Write log file contents to TeamCity build log

Tags: windows, scripting, teamcity, build-automation

A build step in my team city setup produces a log file. How do I include the contents of that file in the build log?

I already tried the "type" command, but that does not work.

I know I could list the file as artifact so I can download it, but it is really just a log file, so the right place would be in the build log.

The command line build step contains the following script:

```
SomeBatch.bat
type LogOutput.txt
```

`SomeBatch.bat` calls an EXE that writes the `LogOutput.txt`.

Comment: What kind of build step is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the `type` command (Windows alternative of `cat`) was the right way to do it, after all. But since the first line of the command line build step is to call a batch file and I forgot to add a "call" statement, the `type` did not work for some reason.

So here is the working build step script:

```
call SomeBatch.bat
type LogOutput.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your build step to output the log to stdout. You can also output the log in teamcity service message format

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

Comment: The point is that I can't log to stdout directly, the log is written to a file. And unfortunately there is no service message to tell TeamCity to read a file and write its contents to the build log. So I'm afraid this is not a solution.